# CSS media query breakpoints are 10% larger in chrome than specified in my CSS

Tags: css

My CSS media query specifies a pixel range of 480-850px, but in Chrome it's kicking in from 528px-935px instead. I'm measuring pixels with chrome developer tools. I thought it might be zoom or something but zoom is set to 100%.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 850px){
#main-nav {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Any ideas what is going on here? This media query works perfectly in Safari. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: that query works just fine, something else is the problem https://jsfiddle.net/j5hqygkx/

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve